# Page not printing right in Chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

This is an interesting problem, and may not be related to my code.

I have a page that is extremely sparse. It is a dynamically created table (with PHP), that has no CSS. It is just a `table` with `tr`s and `td`s, some of which have a `colspan` setting. Any content is just plaintext.

This page prints out perfectly fine in FireFox (not tested in IE) but in Chrome when it prints, the first row (first 4 `td`s) are screwed up.

The divided columns (the borders on the `td`s) are missing, except for the first (left most) one. Also, the left most `td` is missing it's data.

Is there a known issue with Chrome? Is there something I can do to make it print properly?

**Update**

Here's a mockup of how it looks. The circled Green section is how the top most row is actually displayed. The top portion is what the print out looks like.

[image]

Comment: Please check with providing some width to the table data.

Comment: @prava What do you mean? Setting the width on the table? Or providing it in my question?

Comment: I mean to say, add some width for td of your table in your code :)

Comment: @prava the table is, by default, 100% width. What happens is, you can see where the dividers are supposed to be, but they are whited out. I'll see about whipping up a mock screenshot.

Comment: @prava Added an image to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Can you please try with this CSS - `@media print { thead {display: table-header-group; } }`.

Comment: @prava There are no `thead` in my table, but I changed them to it and did that anyway and no change,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59623/discussion-between-prava-and-sharf).